# Solr compiling error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, solr

I check out solr to eclipse, but got the compilation error:

The method setXIncludeAware(boolean) is undefined for the type DocumentBuilderFactory

Does anyone know what's wrong ? Thanks

Jeff Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.class

is included in JRE 1.6 and also in xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar.

The version in the jar is from an older version. Remove the dependency on the jar and see what happens.